# Not getting a parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to get a parameter of a number to record in the database. In the database does not record the number obtained in the input number.

inicializas_controller.rb

```
class InicializasController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!  
  layout 'users_menus'

  def index
    @empresa = Parameter.find(1)

    if request.post?
      begin
        if Inicia.factura
          flash.now[:notice] = "Inicializado el Sistema de Facturacion"
        end  
       rescue
          flash.now[:notice] = "No se ha inicializado"
      end
    end 
  end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="text-center">Inicializacion de Sistema</h2>
  <p class="text-center">
    <%= bootstrap_flash %>
    <%= link_to 'Regresar Menu Principal', root_path, class: 'btn btn-default' %>
  </p>
  <%= form_tag("/inicializas/index", method: "post") do %>
    <%= label_tag(:numero_factura, "Ingresar el numero de la ultima factura:") %>
    <%= number_field_tag(:numero_factura) %>
    <% @numero_factura = params[:numero_factura] %>
    <%= puts 'numero : ' + @numero_factura.to_s %>
    <%= submit_tag "Inicializar", class: Inicia.factura %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

index appeared the "puts" on the console, params

inicia.rb

```
class Inicia
  def self.factura
    p = Time.new
    Invoice.destroy_all
    factura = Invoice.new
    factura.fecha = p.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") 
    factura.impuesto = 'S'
    factura.status_id = 1
    factura.customer_id = 1
    factura.fecha_vencimiento = p.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    factura.orden_compra = 'X'
    factura.pedido = 'X'
    factura.sale_id = 1
    factura.moneda = 'S/.'
    factura.numero_factura = params[:numero_factura]
    factura.save
    Rails.logger.info(factura.errors.inspect)
  end

  def self.get_date
    Time.now.strftime('%F')
  end
end
```

Error:

undefined local variable or method `params' for Inicia:Class

Answer (score 2):

```
undefined local variable or method `params' for Inicia:Class
```

`params` is available in your controller. It's not available in any other places such as models and other classes etc. Hence, you got the above mentioned error.

You can take a look at the `params` implementation in Rails [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb#L21-L34).

Basically, when you write a controller in Rails, you inherit it from the `ApplicationController` which inherits from `ActionController::Base` class. Through this, `params` becomes available in your controller actions. In your case, `Inicia` class is not inheriting from the `ApplicationController` and is not a controller itself. So, you don't have access to `params` in your `Inicia` class.

Hope this makes it clear.

Answer (score 0):

To further `@K M Rakibul Islam`'s excellent answer (which I upvoted), you need to refactor your code.

Specifically, I think you need to put your `class` code into your `Invoice` model, and manage the lot from your controller:

```
#app/controllers/inicializas_controller.rb
class InicializasController < ApplicationController
  def index
    Invoice.destroy_all
    @factura = Invoice.new(factura_params)

    if @factura.save
      flash.now[:notice] = "Inicializado el Sistema de Facturacion"
    else
      flash.now[:notice] = "No se ha inicializado"
    end
  end

  private

  def time
    Time.now
  end

  def factura_params
    {
      fecha: time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"), 
      impuesto: 'S',
      status_id: 1,
      customer_id: 1,
      fecha_vencimiento: time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"),
      orden_compra: 'X',
      pedido: 'X',
      sale_id: 1,
      moneda: 'S/.',
      numero_factura: params[:numero_factura]
   }
  end
end
```

This should fix the errors you're seeing, but still needs some major refactoring to make it as modular as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Friends, Merry Christmas!
Thank you very much for the contribution. Now, I have a doubt in the modified code, I see that records of the database are automatically deleted. I had to add a line of code that if you delete or not. So far everything works. Deputy the correction.

index.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
<h2 class="text-center">Inicializacion de Sistema</h2>
<p class="text-center">
  <%= bootstrap_flash %>
  <%= link_to 'Regresar Menu Principal', root_path, class: 'btn btn-default' %>
</p>

    <%= form_tag("/inicializas/index", method: "post") do %>
      <%= label_tag(:numero_factura, "Ingresar el numero de la ultima factura:") %>
      <%= number_field_tag(:numero_factura) %>
      <% @numero_factura = params[:numero_factura] %>
      <%= label_tag(:respuesta1, "Desea Inicializar el Sistema de Facturacion: (S)i / (N)o") %>
      <%= text_field_tag(:respuesta1, nil, maxlength: 1) %>
      <%= puts 'numero : ' + @numero_factura.to_s %>
      <%= submit_tag "Inicializar" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

inicializas_controller.rb

```
class InicializasController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!  
  layout 'users_menus'

  def index
    @empresa = Parameter.find(1)
    @respuesta1 = params[:respuesta1]

    if @respuesta1 == 'S'
      Invoice.destroy_all
      @factura = Invoice.new(factura_params)

        if @factura.save
          flash.now[:notice] = "Inicializado el Sistema de Facturacion"
        else
          flash.now[:notice] = "No se ha inicializado"
        end
    else
      flash.now[:notice] = "No se ha inicializado el Sistema de Facturacion"
    end 
  end

  private

  def time
    Time.now
  end

  def factura_params
    {
      fecha: time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"), 
      impuesto: 'S',
      status_id: 1,
      customer_id: 1,
      fecha_vencimiento: time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"),
      orden_compra: 'X',
      pedido: 'X',
      sale_id: 1,
      moneda: 'S/.',
      numero_factura: params[:numero_factura]
   }
  end
end
```